# How to test a fake file upload to a route that validate the file in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, file, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to write a test unit for the route 'store' in my controller, pass a fake file to be tested too through the validator of my method, but all i got is that the data is not a file :

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse {
  +baseResponse: Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse {
    #data: "{
              "message":"The given data was invalid.",
              "errors":{"invoice":["The invoice must be a file."]}
           }"
```

**Code :**

- *Test :*

```php
        $data = factory('App\Domain\X\X')->raw(['creator_id' => $user->id]);
        $data['invoice'] = UploadedFile::fake()->create('invoice.xlsx');
        $response = $this->json('POST', route('x.store', $data));
```

- *Controller :*

```php
 public function store(XXXRequest $request)
    {
        ...
```

- *Request :*

```php
class XXXRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'invoice' => 'nullable|file',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

Test:

```
    $data = factory('App\Domain\X\X')->raw(['creator_id' => $user->id]);
    $data['invoice'] = UploadedFile::fake()->create('invoice.xlsx');
    $response = $this->json('POST', route('x.store', $data), [
       'name' => 'abc',
       'invoice' => $data['invoice']
    ]);
```

Comment: Forgot to add data parameter to the json method, of course ! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just create an UploadedFile from a local file and add it to your request:

```php
    use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

    $filename = public_path('tests/invoice.pdf');
    $file = new UploadedFile($filename, 'invoice.pdf', 'application/pdf', filesize($filename), null, true);

    $this->post('/', [
        'invoice' => $file,
    ]);
```

Comment: Not if  I want to use the spatie media library, solution of Jinal worked

Comment: Both solutions work just fine and create a request containing a file. UploadedFile::fake() is under the hood creating a new UploadedFile. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6391166eec77491c83c854fd0c699420eab4aa6e/src/Illuminate/Http/Testing/File.php#L42-L44

Answer (score -1):

You can read about testing file uploads [here](https://laravel-news.com/testing-file-uploads-with-laravel) or visit [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#testing-file-uploads)

```
/**
 * Example 
 *
 * @test 
 */
public function test_correct_file_uploading(): void
{   
    // Set fake storage ('local', 's3', etc)
    Storage::fake('local');
    
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/path_to_your/controller/method', [
        'file' => UploadedFile::fake()->create('invoice.xlsx', 1024)
    ]);

    // Assert response successful
    $response->assertSuccessful();
    
    // Assert the file was stored
    Storage::disk('local')->assertExists('invoice.xlsx');
}
```